# Can tuples implement external data from .txt files?

Tags: python

# Defines the variable 'load_words()'.

```
def load_words():
```

# Opens and assigns a 'word' file from an external "txt" file.

```
       words_file = open("words.txt", "r")
```

# Assigns 'words' as the condensed function for lines of coded words in the external "txt" file.

```
       words = [line.strip() for line in words_file]
```

can you do the same with tuples, without accessing data directly within the program?

Thanks

Comment: Huh? Do clarify your question....

Comment: "Assigns 'words' as the condensed function for lines of coded words in the external "txt" file." What is this supposed to mean? `words` is a list, not a "condensed function" (whatever that is... I have heard of condensed soups, but not condensed functions).

Comment: You are not defining an ordinary variable, you are defining a function.

Comment: Yes, `tuple`s can represent the contents of `words`, similar to the `list` that exists there now.  Is your question regarding tuples versus lists or populating these contents without doing `open()` and file I/O?  Why are you asking this question?

Comment: You could do `words = tuple(line.strip() for line in words_file)`, is that what you mean?

Comment: @BrianCain great, how would you do that is my question?

Comment: @PontiusPilateVII Please don't vandalise your post like that.

Comment: The comments in the code are all wrong. Is this some kind of a trick question or is it just a programmer who doesn't know what (s)he's doing?

Comment: ...The comment was differently written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it makes sense to put that into a tuple instead of a list since once it's there presumably you wouldn't make any changes to it and tuples are faster to access with `in`.

```
WORDLIST = "words.txt"

def loadWords():
    with open(WORDLIST, 'r') as inFile:
        wordTuple = tuple(word.lower() for word in inFile.read().split())
    return wordTuple

MYWORDS = loadWords()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, yes.

From your question, it sounds like you want to read a file with `N` lines, and from that file produce an N-tuple of strings, in which each element of the tuple is a line from the file.

So, what you're doing now is reading a file that looks like this:

```
Hello
World
!
```

and producing the list of strings, `["Hello", "World", "!"]`

What I think you want is the 3-tuple: `("Hello", "World", "!")`

You can do the following:

```
with open("words.txt") as file:
    t = tuple(line.strip() for line in file)
```

which will result in `t` containing the N-tuple of "words.txt"'s contents.
What's happening here is that the expression `line.strip() for line in file` is a generator, being passed to the tuple constructor.
Generators are iterable, and the tuple constructor, when given an iterable, iterates over all elements of the iterable and stuffs them into a tuple.

A quick note: you should not want to or need to do this.
File inputs are beyond your direct control as a programmer, and therefore should be treated as variable length.
Tuples are useful to represent fixed-length constructs, not so much for variable things like files.
Why do you want to do this? What purpose do tuples serve for you which lists do not?

Comment: At least make it `line.strip() for line in file` or else `line for line in file` is useless and you can just use `tuple(file)`

Comment: I've updated to use `line.strip()`. I think it's more important to learn about feeding generator expressions to constructors, or (more fundamentally) when to use a list vs. a tuple, but you're right that there's no point in dropping some of the initial intent.